# Image inside a textbox with a value in it

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have the text box, which has a bck ground no-repeat image in it.

I need to place the image in the right side inside the text box, with a value  "Search", and the back ground color of the text box should be white.

[image]

I need this:-

[image]

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it using z-index.

Try this:

```
<img width="300px" height="200px" style="position:absolute;"/>
<div style="float:left; z-index:2;position:absolute;">
<input type="text" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

To place the background the way you want it, you need to set the background-position property, like so:

```
background-position:right center;
```

Regarding the other styling issues you mentioned in your question:

Setting the background color is done the same way you'd set the background color of any element.

```
background-color:#fff;
```

Getting the placeholder value to be "Search" can be done two ways. You can set the html5 placeholder attribute on your element, like so:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search"/>
```

This is great, as the placeholder value will automatically disappear as soon as the user starts typing in your field. The problem is that the placeholder attribute isn't supported in IE7, 8 or 9. The more cross-browser/backward-compatible way to do this is to set the value of your input, like so:

```
<input type="text" value="Seach"/>
```

And then use some JavaScript to empty out that value when the user clicks into the field.